# Map from Mapbox as layer in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, tilemill

I want to use this map from mapbox as base layer in OpenLayers:

http://mapbox.com/#/tileset/iraq

I used [this example](http://support.mapbox.com/kb/mapbox-tiles/using-mapbox-tiles-with-your-website) to make it work. Everything is fine when I keep the code as it is with original layer "world-light", but when I change it to "iraq", it doesn't work.

I checked it in Firebug and it looks fine - it asks for "iraq" tiles as the original page.

Do you have any ideas how to solve it?
Thanks

Comment: simply change the layername AND file_extension variables to match the values found on the desired tileset's page yours are http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox/1.0.0/iraq/9/318/306.png

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to get to the example on mapbox.com's site.  Might be better to work from the one provided by OpenLayers:

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/mapbox.html